# Laravel: Unsure why I'm getting error for "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

I am getting logs showing `Trying to get property of non-object` and it's pointing to  `'item_name' => $typeName ? $typeName : ! is_null($product) ? $product->name : null,` in the block below.  My logging tool shows that `$typeName` has a string value of `"Elegant Top"` and `product` is `null` at the time of this error but not sure why it would be erroring.

$typeName = $request->input('type_name') ?? null;

```
$newType = Item::create([
      'item_name' => $typeName ? $typeName : ! is_null($product) ? $product->name : null,
      'description' => json_encode($desc),
]);
```

Comment: DO NOT combine multiple ternary statements. Ever.

Comment: Try `'item_name' => $typeName ?: ($product->name ?? null),` or, just create a variable beforehand with a standard `if` statement, instead of stuffing everything into your array constructor.

Comment: Starting PHP 7.4 multiple ternaries without parentheses is deprecated and in PHP 8 it will cause an error so now is the time to adjust to what is coming

Comment: It may have been officially deprecated in 7.4 @apokryfos but they have been warning against it for [much much longer](https://web.archive.org/web/20061013074734/http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).